# How to pass data from service worker to client on notificationclick

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I am new to Service Workers, I would like to pass data from notificationclick to client through post.

Or, on push event, saving data on indexeddb.

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
    const obj = JSON.parse(event.data.text());
    const title = obj.title;
    const options = obj.options;

// options.actions = [{action: "get", title: "Get now."}];
// options.data = {
//     time: new Date(Date.now()).toString(),
//     message: 'Hello, World!'
// };

    save();
    const notificationPromise = self.registration.showNotification(title, options);
    event.waitUntil(notificationPromise);
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    event.notification.close();

    event.waitUntil(
        clients.openWindow('http://localhost/')
    );
});
```

Comment: what you mean is , you want to save the data in indexed db, whenever user clicks on  notification

Comment: I wanna handle (merge with html) on client the data arrive from push message.
One way, I think, will be service worker save the data in indexed db and then get from client when the page is open.